# Не удается сохранить картинку из POST запроса Python

Tags: python, fastapi

**Приветствую!**

Столкнулся с проблемой.

Отправляю POST запрос с картинкой Postman`а
Нужно сохранить файл (картинка в jpg) локально, у себя на компьютере.
Далее эта часть кода будет задействована для другого.

Нигде не нашел как это реализовать.

Отправляю вот так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

написал функцию, имя файла забирает, а как с самим изображением поступить, нет вариантов.

```
@app.post("/asd")
async def create_upload_file(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    print("filename", file.filename)
    return "123"
```

С удовольствием приму любые замечания. Может следует использовать Django для этих целей или что-то другое...

**Заранее благодарю**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**done**

Все оказалось на порядок легче

```
@app.post("/asd")
async def create_upload_file(uploaded_file: UploadFile = File(...)):    
    file_location = f"/home/ilya/test2/{uploaded_file.filename}"
    with open(file_location, "wb+") as file_object:
        # shutil.copyfileobj(uploaded_file.file, file_object)
        file_object.write(uploaded_file.file.read())
    return {"info": f"file '{uploaded_file.filename}' saved at '{file_location}'"}
```

файл из пост-запроса сохраняется по пути home/ilya/test2/
ключ запроса изменен на uploaded_file

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]